# change sudoers to stop asking for password when running a systemsetup comman

Tags: macos, terminal, sudo

To what exactly do I need to change sudoers file to prevent asking for password when I change system time zone?

This is the command I am going to run:

```
sudo systemsetup -settimezone timezone
```

I know I need to change it, but I feel uncomfortable changing sudoers on my own due to not knowing exactly what I am doing.

Answer (score 8):

Was brave enough to do it myself. For future readers, add:

```
yourusername ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/systemsetup
```

after

```
## User privilege specification
##
root ALL=(ALL) ALL
%admin  ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

Comment: You should also add running "sudo visudo" first

Answer (score 2):

To enable passwordless sudo for *all* admin users on the machine:

1. Run `sudo visudo`
2. Change the line reading `%admin  ALL=(ALL) ALL` to `%admin  ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD ALL`
3. Save changes (press Escape, type :wq! at the command prompt and hit enter).

Answer (score 1):

issue

```
sudo visudo
```

and assure file contains these lines ( replace yourusername )

```
root ALL=(ALL) ALL
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL
yourusername  ALL=(ALL) ALL
```